# Atlas search array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I have the following schema:

```
{
   name: String,
   phones: [
        {
            number: String,
            type: String
        }
   ]
}
```

How do I index `phones.number` so that I can write something like:

```
collection.aggregate([{
       "$search":{ 
            "compound":{
                  "should":[
                      {"autocomplete":{"query":"012345","path":"name"}},
                      {"autocomplete":{"query":"012345","path":"phones.number"}}
                  ]
             }
         }
}])
```

The docs [here](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/index-definitions#static-mapping-example) give an example for an array of strings but not an array of objects.

Comment: Autocomplete is not a valid index definition for arrays either, afaik,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6104971/8289095), indexing by a property of a subdocument in an array is supported. Just create an index by `phones.number`.

See [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#multikey-index) for more information.

---

**EDIT**

I was confusing standard indexing with indexing for Atlas Search. From the documentation, you should be able to index an array of documents this way:

```
{
  "analyzer":"lucene.standard",
  "searchAnalyzer":"lucene.standard",
  "mappings":{
    "dynamic":false,
    "fields":{
      "name":{
        "type":"string",
        "analyzer":"lucene.standard"
      },
      "phones":{
        "type":"document",
        "fields":{
          "number":{
            "type":"string",
            "analyzer":"lucene.standard"
          },
          "type":{
            "type":"string",
            "analyzer":"lucene.standard"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Dot notation is actually not supported in the way you are thinking. Users need to specify the phones field as a type `document` and its object members accordingly. See the documentation here on index definitions: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/index-definitions#document

Comment: @Nice-Guy Does the example on this link not apply for a multi key index in this context? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/

Comment: @Nice-Guy Sorry, I see I have confused starboard indexing with indexing for Atlas Search.

Comment: Thanks it helped. @Chris, does the order of the indexed fields of atlas search matters for our query(highly selective / least selective ) to perfom well ?

Comment: I’m not sure how much the order matters. Sorry. Glad the answer helped!

Comment: yayyyÿÿyyyyyyyy

Comment: @FirojSiddiki might be little late but no the order of fields in index mapping doesn't matter in mongodb atlas indexes.